# Comparison between lm() and cor() - why the results are not corresponding

Tags: r, correlation, lm

I am running an analysis for my dataset, example data frame df:

```
   DOY     species replicate position      SLA      PAR      temp    A1200    susPQ    susNPQ      FvFm      
1:  46 LINGONBERRY         1      LOW 65.75638 19.70906 -2.850833 0.569690 2.147297 0.9321771 0.5263661 562.1016 0.011440    28.02628
2:  46 LINGONBERRY         2      LOW 59.45028 19.78096 -2.850833 0.893840 2.511543 1.0516496 0.5503916 533.6136 0.028930    25.40703
3:  46 LINGONBERRY         3      LOW 59.51058 17.52833 -2.850833 0.731765 2.278927 1.0678274 0.5242824 549.6316 0.020185    46.16188
4:  46        PINE         1      LOW 35.90156 20.85151 -2.850833 1.518910 2.319431 2.2168853 0.4189484 392.6067 0.059280    47.79101
5:  46        PINE         1      TOP 27.29495 90.27197 -2.850833 1.780420 1.739912 1.5691443 0.4037803 418.3636 0.032890    59.03595
6:  46        PINE         2      LOW 34.38626 27.86268 -2.850833 1.959910
```

I want to check correlations between my variables, so I use `cor()` and `rcor()` functions.

```
cor.df <-corrplot(cor(df[,c(1,5:19)], method = "pearson"), method = "number", type = "upper", 
                  tl.col = "black")   

df_matrix <- as.matrix(df[,c(1,5:19)])
rcor.df <- rcorr(df_matrix, type ="pearson")

cor.df_R <-corrplot(rcor.df$r, method = "number", type = "upper", tl.col = "black", 
                    p.mat = rcor.df$P, sig.level = 0.001)
```

[r-correlation plot for my variables with "unsignificant" correlations crossed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpAeZ.png)

As the results were not what I expected, I wanted to double-check that the method is working. To test that, I wanted to simply put some variables pairs into `lm()`. My assumption was that R2 from `lm()` summary should be the same as values delivered in my `corplot`. But, that is not the case.

1/ What is wrong with my assumption? Why `lm()` R2 does not correspond to `rcor()` or `cor()` r?
2/ What would be a suitable test to check that my correlations delivered in `corplot` are trustworthy? It is always good to run a backup test in case our results show something contradicting to the literature (as it is the case here).

Comment: Without a reproducible example I can only guess. Maybe this is related to handling of missing values?

Comment: You can compare the `cor()^2` with R^2.

Answer (score 6):

The R² of a simple linear regression is not the correlation but the *square* of the correlation between the independent variable and the dependent variable.

```r
x <- 1:5
y <- rnorm(5)

cor(x, y)^2
# 0.001016668
summary(lm(y ~ x))$r.squared
# 0.001016668
```

Comment: That answers my question! I like when the solution is so simple. Thank you!